# Forms GUI with 2 comboboxes to check an bool array in a webmethod

Tags: c#, combobox, webmethod

hi im having trouble finding a way to have a webmethod check to see if the selected spot from the combo boxes if false. the combo boxes is to select a pier and a mooring. in the array tru is taken false is free.(well thats what i hope will happen). here some of the webmethod ive done.

edit i need to write a webmethed that calls 2 ints from 2 comboboxes and then check if that slot in the array is free. and if its not free select the next avilable slot. the array is for the pier and moorings.

```
[WebMethod]
    public ReserveMooringResponse getMooring(ReserveMooringRequest req)
    {
        var resv = new ReserveMooringResponse();

        int pier = 0;
        int mooring = 0;
        bool checkSeat = false;
        string firstName;

        bool[,] mooringArray = new bool[,] {{ true, false, true, false, true}, //pier 1
                                        {true, false, false, true, true}, //pier 2
                                        {false, true, true, false, true}, //pier 3
                                        {false, false, true, false, true}, //pier 4
                                        {true, false, false, true, true},  //pier 5
                                        {true, true, false, false, false}}; //pier 6


        return resv;
    }
```

Comment: I can't understand your requirement. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Check my latest edit, i fixed a recursion bug.

Comment: let me know if I missed the boat.  @SimonWhitehead hows that look to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got the jist of what you are working on.  Basically, you want a recursion that tests your array for pier and mooring.  If true, then reserve the mooring, if false, then move on to find an open one.

Some assumptions:

- `ReserveMooringResponse` is a class with 2 properties, Pier and Mooring.
- `ReserveMooringRequest` is a class with 2 properties, Pier and Mooring.
- Note that I hardcoded the pier and the mooring.  You would replace this with `(int)combobox1.SelectedValue` and `(int)combobox2.SelectedValue`
- I moved the `WebMethod` attribute to the `CheckReservation` method.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var pier = 3;
        var mooring = 3;
        //set up client
        var service = new Service1();
        var resv = service.CheckReservation(pier, mooring);

        label1.Text = string.Format("Reservation for Pier {0} and Mooring {1} confirmed.", resv.Pier, resv.Mooring);
    }
}

public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    bool[,] mooringArray = new bool[,] {{ true, false, true, false, true}, //pier 1
                                    {true, false, false, true, true}, //pier 2
                                    {false, true, true, false, true}, //pier 3
                                    {false, false, true, false, true}, //pier 4
                                    {true, false, false, true, true},  //pier 5
                                    {true, true, false, false, false}}; //pier 6

    public ReserveMooringResponse getMooring(ReserveMooringRequest req)
    {
        var resv = new ReserveMooringResponse();

        if (req.mooring > 4)
        {
            req.mooring--;
            req.pier++;
        }

        resv.Pier = req.pier;
        resv.Mooring = req.mooring;

        if (!mooringArray[req.pier, req.mooring])
        {
            var mooring = req.mooring;
            mooring++;
            resv = this.getMooring(new ReserveMooringRequest
            {
                mooring = mooring,
                pier = req.pier
            });
        }

        mooringArray[resv.Pier, resv.Mooring] = false;
        return resv;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public ReserveMooringResponse CheckReservation(int pier, int mooring)
    {
        var req = new ReserveMooringRequest
        {
            pier = pier,
            mooring = mooring
        };
        return this.getMooring(req);
    }
```